# What is Git Submodule workflow for projects with modules which located in many directories?

Tags: git, magento, github

What is Git Submodule workflow for projects with modules which located in many directories?

This screen describes what exactly I need http://gyazo.com/6c4a6f8d5ed19a9e80abd4b101675cb5 or good description in like [Git submodule or sub-repository or remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437460/git-submodule-or-sub-repository-or-remote).

Every module/theme/plugin have separate repository/subrepository.

But problem is when module located in different directories(related problem desctibes in [Best practices for using Git with Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564622/best-practices-for-using-git-with-magento))
I tried did it with Modgit-git-plugin, BUT

1) I'm not sure that is the best solution for this problem. Guys what do you think?
2) I can't synchronize modgit source folder with module and files in root of site, for example, see my actions:
A. modgit clone magento-turpentine https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine.git

I get:
(A-files) module

> ```
>           shell/*
>           app/etc/modules/*
>           app/code/community/*
>           app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/S*
>           app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/turpentine/*
> ```
>
> (B-files) .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/
>
> ```
>           .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/shell/*
>           .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/app/etc/modules/*
>           .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/app/code/community/*
>           .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/S*
>           .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/turpentine/*
> ```

B. modgit update-all

C. Than I create new remote repository and pushed
cd .modgit/magento-turpentine/source/
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:myteam/magento-turpentine-test.git
git push -u origin master

I have two programmers,
1st work with (A-files)
2nd work with (B-Files)(only with this git@bitbucket.org:myteam/magento-turpentine-test.git repository) 
What is the right methods synchronize files in root(main repository) and .modgit/module/source/.git... repository?

Conclusions: 
1) I'm not sure that is the best solution for this problem. Guys what do you think?
2) I can't synchronize modgit(details above), please help.